# How does Typescript relate the type definition for what we are importing with the corresponding implementation?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript2.2

When we use libraries typedefinition (.d.ts) files how does typescript relate the definition of what we are importing with the corresponding type?

For example if we:

```
npm install @types/chai @types/mocha --save-dev
```

Then inside `bar.spec.js`:

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
```

Typescript now understand the typed facade for `expect`?  What process does it go through to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type definitions are pretty complex in my opinion, with a long evolutionary history.

In this case `node_modules/@types` is sort of a built in "type root" so TS knows when you import a non-relative module (ex `"chai"` is non-relative, `"./chai"` is relative) to look for definitions in `node_modules/@types` for resolution. For example `from "chai"` results in TS finding `node_modules/@types/chai/index.d.ts` for the definition. This is how TS knows what you can import from that module and what those things look like.

You can read more about [module resolution in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html).

How the `.d.ts` file is written can be hard to follow (particularly because most published libraries [support several module system flavors](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) simultaneously) but in short chai [exports](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chai/index.d.ts#L1247) an [interface `ChaiStatic` that describes the shape of the module](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chai/index.d.ts#L15) which includes a member [`expect`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chai/index.d.ts#L16) of type [`ExpectStatic`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chai/index.d.ts#L28). So that's how TS knows what `import { expect } from "chai"` is.

Also worth pointing out is that it seems Chai's current definitions don't quite seem to follow the [latest way to define a UMD module](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7125). This doesn't make them incompatible in any way, though.